# NodeJS Express encodes the URL - how to decode

Tags: node.js, express, escaping

I'm using NodeJS with Express, and when I use foreign characters in the URL, they automatically get encoded.

**How do I decode it back to the original string?**

Before calling NodeJS, I escape characters.

So the string: `אובמה`

Becomes `%u05D0%u05D5%u05D1%u05DE%u05D4`

The entire URL now looks like: `http://localhost:32323/?query=%u05D0%u05D5%u05D1%u05DE%u05D4`

Now in my NodeJS, I get the escaped string `%u05D0%u05D5%u05D1%u05DE%u05D4`.

This is the relevant code:

```
var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
var params = url_parts.query;
var query = params.query; // '%u05D0%u05D5%u05D1%u05DE%u05D4'
```

I've tried `url` and `querystring` libraries but nothing seems to fit my case.

```
querystring.unescape(query); // still '%u05D0%u05D5%u05D1%u05DE%u05D4'
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**Update 16/03/18**

`escape` and `unescape` are [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape).

Use:
`encodeURIComponent('אובמה') // %D7%90%D7%95%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%94`

`decodeURIComponent('%D7%90%D7%95%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%94') // אובמה`

**Old answer**

`unescape('%u05D0%u05D5%u05D1%u05DE%u05D4')` gives `"אובמה"`

Try:

`var querystring = unescape(query);`

Comment: This is deprecated for long years now: http://cwestblog.com/2011/05/23/escape-unescape-deprecated/

Comment: Use `querystring.unescape(str)` instead

Answer (score 27):

You should use `decodeURI()` and `encodeURI()` to encode/decode a URL with foreign characters.

Usage:

```
var query = 'http://google.com';
query = encodeURI(query);
query = decodeURI(query); // http://google.com
```

Reference on MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI

Comment: I'm using Express (as stated) and I only have the partial URL with just the params. So `decodeURI(query)` returns a `malformed uri` error. I don't see how I can use it in this case.

Comment: Use `encodeURIComponent` and `decodeURIComponent`. These will work in case you do not have a full URI that needs to be encoded.

Answer (score 0):

**Decoding query parameters from a URL**

decodeURIComponent cannot be used directly to parse query parameters from a URL. It needs a bit of preparation.

```
function decodeQueryParam(p) {
  return decodeURIComponent(p.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

console.log(decodeQueryParam('search+query%20%28correct%29'));
// 'search query (correct)'
```

SOURCE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent#decoding_query_parameters_from_a_url

Answer (score -3):

````
#**update may-2020**
# how to use an encoder/decoder on node js
### I am writing my answer due to I have noisy data I spend 4 hour to fixed

data email   input = myemail@gmail.com
data URL input = /us/home

```
decodeURI function that only decodes a URL special character 

  email output =>myemail%40gmail.com 
  url output => %2Fus%2F

using decodeURIComponent 
  email output = > myemail@gmail.com
  url output => /us/
```
here some clarification where you can use decodeURI and  decodeURIComponent   a fucntion
````

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything to the other answers and in addition is unclear and confusing. Why is everything formatted as code? Where is the clarification that's mentioned? It states that it'll explain how to use encoding but only has a reference to  `decodeURIComponent` end even there doesn't really show how to use it. It wastes people's time and might even confuse them.

Comment: is this an answer?