# URL as parameter in Express

Tags: node.js, express, url, routes, query-string

Using Node.js with Express, how do I accept a URL as a parameter?

i.e http://example.com/site/http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com

I have the following handler

```
app.get('/site/:dest', function (req, res, next) {
   res.end('URL = ' + req.params.dest);
});
```

Rather than getting the expected response i get a 404:

> The requested URL /site/http://www.google.com was not found on this
>   server.

If i request example.com/site/hello it works fine, but not for passing a URL. I assume its the forward slashes escaping that's causing the problem.

Is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: I suggest u switching to use the `req.query` instead of the `req.params`

Comment: @FelixFong Thankyou! Your approach did the trick, i'll post the fix below

Comment: Cuz I had this issue before, happy coding <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround:

Changed the routing and now using `req.query`

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
   res.end('URL = ' + req.query['site']);
});
```

Now, http://example.com/?site=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%3Fhello%3Dworld%26foo%3Dbar works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

It's worked for me

```
app.get('/site/*', function (req, res, next) {
  res.end('URL = ' + req.params[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode your parameter's URL. You will have a lot of issues if you just send the URL as a param.

Best way is to `url encode` the param and on your nodejs side you will need to `url decode`

Example: 
https://www.google.com will be `https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com`

Comment: Do you know where i would need to put the decode method as the routing is handled by the Express framework?

Comment: I think this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34576659/nodejs-express-encodes-the-url-how-to-decode

the decode need to be inside your handler. Your url will be a param, you will just need to decode the param to have your url back