# Want To know the Deoding Method

Tags: node.js, encoding, decode, urlencode

I wanted to decode my PUBG name. I come to interact with this site: http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/

It decodes as I want, but now I want to know what technique they use, so I can use it in my project.

Input :

> PSYCH%C3%98%E4%B9%82JOKER

Decoded String:

> PSYCHØ乂JOKER

Here Is The result Url: http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/?results=48d3b517a922349a1838240623f6e7c3

Comment: I changed the tags to what it really is, enconding and not encryption. In this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34576659/nodejs-express-encodes-the-url-how-to-decode) you can see how to encode and decode it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [Percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), this is a way to encode stuff to be valid written in URLs. The characters after the `%` symbol are just the hexadecimal UTF-8 values to encode the special characters Ø乂.

`0xC3 0x98` corresponds to Ø and `0xE4 0xB9 0x82` to 乂 in UTF-8.

By the way, since you added the *encryption* badge and wrote the word in your question. In this situation, we cannot speak of decryption; you might want to take a look at the difference between all that terminology (encoding and encryption, for example).

Comment: The answer is here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34576659/nodejs-express-encodes-the-url-how-to-decode)