# special characters are encoded in nodejs Express. how to decode it?

Tags: node.js, express

I tried following these [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34576659/nodejs-express-encodes-the-url-how-to-decode) but couldn't get the URI decoded. how can I go about this?

When I enter a city like `http://localhost:5000/weather?weatherCity=Malmö` the URL changes to this `http://localhost:5000/weather?weatherCity=Malm%C3%B6`,
How can I decode the last part and what am I doing wrong?

```
app.get('/weather', (req, res) => {
  const weatherCity = (req.query.weatherCity)
  let decodeURI = decodeURIComponent(weatherCity) //<------- trying to decode the query
  request(weatherURL(decodeURI), function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    const data = JSON.parse(body)
    return res.send(data)
  });
})

function weatherURL(weatherCity){
  return `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${weatherCity}&units=metric&appid=${process.env.APIKEY}&lang=en`
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS Express encodes the URL - how to decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34576659/nodejs-express-encodes-the-url-how-to-decode)

Comment: Changes where exactly? I'd assume it's only correct to pass encoded parameter string to that api call.

Comment: `decodeURIComponent('Malm%C3%B6')` returns `"Malmö"`

Comment: @flakerimi when i passed decodeURIComponent(weatherCity) the response I got was {"cod":"404","message":"city not found"}.

Comment: https://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=Malm%C3%B6&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02&units=metric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you need:

```js
app.get('/weather', (req, res) => {
  const weatherCity = req.query.weatherCity;
  request(weatherURL(weatherCity), function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    const data = JSON.parse(body)
    return res.send(data)
  });
})

function weatherURL(weatherCity){
  return `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${encodeURIComponent(weatherCity)}&units=metric&appid=${process.env.APIKEY}&lang=en`
}
```

1. There should be no need to decode `req.query.weatherCity` because express does this automatically.
2. You *do* need to encode weatherCity before building a URL with it. URL query parameters should be URL encoded.
3. Consider using something other than `request` because it is deprecated and doesn't support promises. `node-fetch` and `axios`, among others, are good choices.